# c# order by distance from coordinates

Tags: c#, linq, coordinates

I am trying to work out how to get the closest possible line to a given coordinate.

A line is an array of coordinates of type LatLng. LatLng has two properties Latitude and Longitude as well as a method that calculates the distance from the current LatLng to another passed in value. My line list looks like this:

`IEnumerable<LatLng[]> lines.`

Giving a LatLng coordinate, how do I find the closest possible line to the coordinate.

I have tried:

```
lines.OrderBy(line => line.Select(x => x.Distance(coordinate))).First();
```

I am receiving the error "At least one object must implement IComparable.". I am aware that LatLng doesn't implement this but I am not trying to compare on that. I am trying to orderby the distances and then take the closest.

Comment: Why do you have a list of lists?

Comment: Xanatos, the return type of Distance() is of type double.

Comment: So you want to order the outer list by the distance of the closest item in the inner list?

Comment: You have a set of polylines (`LatLng[]`). You need to calculate distance from each segment (pair of `LatLng`) to your point (not a distance of polyline points to your point), and take the smallest. That will be distance from point to your polilyne. Then you `OrderBy` your lines by that distance.

Comment: DavidG, correct.

Comment: Then something like `lines.OrderBy(line => line.Select(x => x.Distance(coordinate)).Min());`?

Comment: DavidG, I'm still getting 'At least one object must implement IComparable.' with your example.

Comment: Did you copy/paste that exactly? It cannot give you that error assuming your description of `LatLng` is accurate.

Comment: Maybe create an in between list with the distances already calculated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a *nested* enumerable of your `LatLng` class, you need to return a numeric value from the inner part of your lambda, and as it seems you are trying to order the outer list by the distance of the closest item in the inner list, this should do the job:

```
var orderedList = lines.OrderBy(line => 
    line.Select(x => 
        x.Distance(coordinate))
        .Min());
```

In fact you can simplify this by removing the `Select` and putting the lambda inside the `Min`:

```
var orderedList = lines.OrderBy(line => 
    line.Min(x => x.Distance(coordinate)));
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, this worked perfectly. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: But that is not correct. I mean it compiles, but distance from polyline to point is not calculated like that

Comment: @cullimorer Well if your coords draw lines, you need to work out the distance to the line, not the point. Imagine a square with a point on one of the lines, it's zero distance away, but my code above will tell you it's not.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but the coordinate will always either be at one of the points on the line, or very close to one - not the line itself. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well if it works for you then fine, just be aware of this limitation.

Comment: Thanks DavidG. One modification, how would I change your code so that if will only return a value closest, if the distance value is less than 0.01?